# What's the easiest way to test a createUIDefinion.json file for Azure solution templates?

Tags: json, azure, azure-marketplace

I'm in the process of publishing my solution template in the Azure marketplace.

My mainTemplate.json file, for example, is easy to test without publishing because I can deploy from Git. But I can't seem to test the UI file via Git deployment.

So the problem is getting my createUIdefinition.json file tested in a timely fashion. It seems like every time I made a change to the createUIdefinition.json file, I have to upload a new package to the publishing portal, which means I have to wait for Microsoft certification before I can stage a test. It's a 24-hour process.

Is there an easier way to test my createUIdefinition.json changes without going through that process?

For example, I have a bug somewhere in the regex that validates one of my user inputs:

```
 {
        "name": "EmailUser",
        "type": "Microsoft.Common.TextBox",
        "label": "Email Address",
        "toolTip": "The email address for your account",
        "defaultValue": "",
        "constraints": {
          "required": true,
          "regex": "\\w+([-+.']\\w+)*@\\w+([-.]\\w+)*\\.\\w+([-.]\\w+)*",
          "validationMessage": "Must be a valid email address."
  }
```

(Side note, if anyone can spot my bug -- maybe when escaping the characters? -- please let me know! No email address validates properly.)

And it's driving me a bit batty having to wait a day just to test my supposed fixes. There must be a better way, thanks!

Comment: Did you find a solution to your constraint regex problem?  I have a similar problem.

Comment: So the regex has to be json-encoded, hence the \\. It turned out I had another syntax problem that was causing the UI to fail, too. I can't remember exactly what that other problem was but using the Azure preview link made it easier to track down. I think it was something silly like the parameter being named incorrectly in bottom of the UI script when setting vars.

Comment: FYI, I ended up going with this for constraints on an email address:
   
    "constraints": {
        "required": true,
        "regex": "^\\S+@\\S+[\\.][0-9a-z]+$",
        "validationMessage": "Must be a valid email address"
     }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure have now a sandbox to test the createUiDefinition file.

https://portal.azure.com/?feature.customPortal=false#view/Microsoft_Azure_CreateUIDef/SandboxBlade

Just copy and paste your createUiDefinition.json content and click preview, it will generate all the ui so you can test your configuration.

You can also view a few examples or get the fields definitions from there.

[image: Create UI Definition Sandbox]

[image: Create UI Definition Sandbox]

Answer (score 6):

I found my answer. There's a specially crafted URL that can be used to preview createUIDefinition.json. The format is like this:

```
<a href="https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Compute/CreateMultiVmWizardBlade/internal_bladeCallId/anything/internal_bladeCallerParams/{"initialData":{},"providerConfig":{"createUiDefinition":"URL_ENCODED_LINK TO_createUiDefinition.json"}}">[Preview createUiDefinition.json]</a>
```

So the steps to test are:

1. upload createUIdefinition.json to a public-accessible URL (github or Azure blob storage both work fine)
2. Modify the above link with the full URL to your file.
3. Paste it into a browser.
4. Login to Azure when prompted, you will be redirected to your UI blade(s).
5. Use F12 to bring up your script console in your browser to see the json-formatted output after filling in your UI values.

Note that you can't do a full deployment here, these steps are only for testing your UI, validating your regex, etc. You still need to test the output and make sure it works with your mainTemplate.json file with a separate deployment.

Comment: Rocky could you take a look at my problem ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37862165/publish-arm-templates-in-azure-portal. It seems that you already know how to publish your ARM template deployment in azure on publish.azure.com

Comment: @Rocky if I modify something in the createUiDefinition file, my UI blades do not reflect the change immediately, even if in starting a new session or renaming "anything" to sg else, just if some time elapses. Can you help how to circumvent this?

Comment: @Diepie sounds like a caching issue. I haven't experienced it -- maybe try a different browser?

Comment: This method does not seem to be working at the moment. I attempted it and it loaded the UI and then displayed an error about location() being null.

Answer (score 4):

The Azure Portal now has a more intuitive way of testing. Go to [aka.ms/createuidef/sandbox](https://ms.portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_CreateUIDef/SandboxBlade), paste your createUiDefinition.json, and click preview to see how it looks. This way you can make changes and see them in real-time without having to republish.

Comment: This is very obscure and very useful!

Answer (score 0):

I found easiest mehtod to test createUiDefinition.json for azure solution template.

1. Go to http://old.armviz.io/#/
2. Click On **Portal UI Editor**.
3. Paste Your content from createUiDefinition.json file to **Portal UI Editor**.
4. Click on Preview button Section. it will take you into azure portal to test createUiDefinition.json file.

Comment: Don't use this method. It is old and has compatibility issues. The Sandbox is much better.

Answer (score -1):

but testing ui template without publishing package is still not possible. sometimes arm template and logical function used in uidefinition get evaluated at runtime only.