# Publish ARM templates in azure portal

Tags: azure

My company is working on deploying our solution using ARM templates on azure, we have got the deployment part working and have a proper working CreateUiDefinition.json file.

We want to publish this now so that our customers can find this solution as an app in the azure marketplace and install it.

on 'publish.azure.com' i can see that we need a zip file with all our templates and other scripts/files which are needed in the deployment.
I uploaded that zip in a topology under the solution template tab, but to get that certified i need run a certification tool or something.

Basically my question is, does anyone know how we can publish our ARM deployment so it gets shown in the azure marketplace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track. Go through all the steps on the publish.windowsazure.com account. You will eventually need to pay the ~$100 fee for a developer account in order to publish live, but you can stage and test before you pay.

[The certification tool is here.](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44299) It will output another zip file that you upload when requesting certification. Seems to take a few hours to a day for a certification to be approved for staging.

Certification is not the same as publishing! Certification will allow you to "stage" your solution template to an Azure Subscription ID of your choice. Then you can search for your staged template from that subscription and test an end-to-end deployment.

It's all in the publishing portal, just a matter of going through the steps. When you register/pay for the developer account, you'll receive an email from Microsoft with various ways to contact them for help. You can call them, too, they're pretty good about supporting ISVs, especially for Azure.

Reply in comments and maybe we can push this to a chat if you have more questions, happy to help, just got a solution published so I'm familiar with the process.

Comment: Thanks for your imput, i would love to start a chat to discuss this more, especially the zip and tool. here's my skype acc: kenneth_verbeure. If you rather use another chat thats ok too

Comment: @Kenneth I created an SE chat room here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41314/microsoft-azure